# Error Using Angular2 File Uploader

Tags: javascript, angular

My ERROR code. In ng2-uploader/src dont have classes.js , but have classes folder with index.js .

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-uploader/src/classes.js 404 (Not Found)
```

IMPORT module in module.ts

```
import { Ng2UploaderModule } from 'ng2-uploader';
```

CONFIG file

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ng2-uploader':'npm:ng2-uploader'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-uploader':{
         main: 'ng2-uploader.js',
         defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

What can i do ??? I have bad skill in angular 2 .